# Was there ever an Anabaptist movement in the Eastern Orthodox Church?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, reformation, anabaptism

Since the original Great Schism, the Orthodox church has seemed pretty unified (at least compared to the Catholic Church). During the radical reformation, Anabaptists were persecuted throughout Germany and Switzerland. This led to some settling in present day Russia and Ukraine.

Was there any point where a similar movement occurred in the Eastern Orthodox church?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Was there ever a "Martin Luther" or a reformation in the Eastern Orthodox Church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/66595/was-there-ever-a-martin-luther-or-a-reformation-in-the-eastern-orthodox-church)

Comment: Not really, because Anabaptists were settling in Orthodox areas in the 1700s. I would like to know if there was any movement to merge Anabaptism with Eastern Orthodox. For instance, they may have disagreed on non violence, but agreed on adult baptisn

Comment: "Was there any point where a similar movement occurred in the Eastern Orthodox church?" - Similar to what?

Comment: A truly internal movement, appearing naturally within the faith, whose birth was wholly uninfluenced from the outside world ? No.

Comment: See [Christian Evangelical Church of Romania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Evangelical_Church_of_Romania) and [Evangelical Church of Romania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelical_Church_of_Romania).